# Oracle - how to convert declare cursor statment to stored procedure

Tags: oracle

I tried a lot to create procedure with cursor with no success.

In declare it's working:

```
DECLARE 
sid varchar(20);
CURSOR mycursor IS 
SELECT SID
FROM "V$SESSION";

BEGIN
    OPEN MYCURSOR;
    LOOP
        FETCH mycursor INTO SID;
        EXIT WHEN mycursor%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SID);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE mycursor;
END;
```

But when I try to put it in a stored procedure and call it, I get invalid state error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SYSTEM.getSessionInfo
AS
sid varchar(20);
 CURSOR mycursor IS 
SELECT SID
FROM "V$SESSION";

BEGIN
    OPEN MYCURSOR;
    LOOP
        FETCH mycursor INTO SID;
        EXIT WHEN mycursor%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SID);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE mycursor;
END;

CALL SYSTEM.getSessionInfo(1)
```

I tried to take working examples from blogs but I don't success to run them.

(I get the same error)

So what is wrong with my code?

Comment: show the complete error stack.  Also NEVER create your own procedures in SYSTEM or SYS schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was I missed:
I had to do more grant command to get all permissions:

```
SQL> grant select_catalog_role to USERNAME

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant select any dictionary to USERNAME

Grant succeeded.
```

and after the one I tried before:

```
SQL> grant select on v_$session to USERNAME;

Grant succeeded.
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong? At least three things.

1. don't abuse SYS, SYSTEM and similar users. They aren't supposed to be used for your playground. Create another one, grant privileges on objects you plan to use and create procedures over there
2. you created a procedure that doesn't accept any parameters, but still - when calling it - you passed `1` as a parameter. Why?
3. you don't `call` a procedure; use `begin-end` block, it works always, everywhere

---

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> grant select on v_$session to scott;

Grant succeeded.
```

Move to an *ordinary* user:

```
SQL> connect scott@pdb1
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> create or replace procedure getsessioninfo
  2  as
  3    sid varchar(20);
  4    cursor mycursor is
  5      select sid
  6      from v$session;
  7  begin
  8      open mycursor;
  9      loop
 10          fetch mycursor into sid;
 11          exit when mycursor%notfound;
 12          dbms_output.put_line(sid);
 13      end loop;
 14      close mycursor;
 15  end;
 16  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> begin
  2    getsessioninfo;
  3  end;
  4  /
1
2
3
4
9
14
16
17
124
<snip>
868
874
878
879

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

As of `call`ing it:

```
SQL> call  getsessioninfo;
call  getsessioninfo
      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name


SQL>
```

You can, though, `exec` it, but only if your client tool allows it:

```
SQL> exec  getsessioninfo;
1
2
3
4
<snip>
```

Comment: I took exactly the create procedure that been succeeded for you and this is the result:
Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors. Do you think it because I use system user? I don't success to create another user with privilage to connect with him.

Comment: Run `select * From user_errors where name = 'GETSESSIONINFO';` to see *which* errors you have; then fix them.